# Any way to generate XSD basing on table with field names and formats?

Tags: xml

Given I have a table which describes my data format in a following way:

```
FieldName FieldType FieldTypeLength IsMandatory

name      string    20              true
age       int       -               false
```

I want to generate an XSD file from this, with corresponding restrictions and tag names.

A question is: can you suggest some tool, or soft for this? I dont want to do it manually.

PS No hierarchy and composition is supposed to be.

UPDATE

OS: Windows

InputFormat: CSV or Excel

Price: no infomation. May be our organisation may buy it, may be no.